# Data dis selected from spinner when use intent and pick the pdf from storage android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**hi hope you are doing well i am facing an issue while setting the data on spinner when i use intent to
get file from storage it dis select the selected data in the spinner**

```
private void getPDF() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
        }

        //creating an intent for file chooser
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Document"), PICK_PDF_CODE);
    }
```